# If $a^3-b^3=2 \ \text{ and }\ a^5-b^5 \ge 4$, then $a^2+b^2 \ge 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, factoring

Prove that if
$$a^3-b^3=2 \ \text{ and }\ a^5-b^5 \ge 4$$
then $$a^2+b^2 \ge 2.$$

Comment: what kind of numbers are $$a,b$$?

Comment: Maybe start with $$(a^3-b^3)(a^2+b^2)=a^5-b^5+a^2 b^2(a-b)$$

Comment: a, b can be any kind of numbers.
If we start with the thing which is above, we will have to prove that a^2b^2(a-b) is always positive, then we will solve it. But how to do it?

Comment: $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+b^2+ab)=2$$ You need to show that $a^2+b^2+ab>0$

Comment: @idliketodothis:  $a^3 - b^3 = 2$ implies that $a > b$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the conditions we have $\frac{a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4}{a^2+ab+b^2}\geq2$.

Thus, it remains to prove that $a^2+b^2\geq\frac{a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4}{a^2+ab+b^2}$, which is $a^2b^2\geq0$.

Done!

Comment: How does proving that a^2+b^2 is greater or equal than the fraction help in solving the problem?

Comment: @idliketodothis If $a^2+b^2\geq\frac{a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4}{a^2+ab+b^2}$ and $\frac{a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4}{a^2+ab+b^2}\geq2$ so $a^2+b^2\geq2$.